# how to get table and column suggestions in ms access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I need expert opinion for MS Access (2010 version). While writing a query in ms access, it is difficult to check for column to join a table and I need to use our dbms chart all the time. IS there any way like we have in SQL management studio which starts showing table and columns name once we start writing query. Also MS access gives weird error message where as SQL shows red line as error message. Is there any way to get red line as error message in SQL?

Kindly guide me on this.

Comment: Why have you not considered using a Query builder? The Access' GUI ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. It would be great if you can throw some light on it.

Comment: Any comment on above question?

Comment: More information : http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/training/use-design-view-to-create-a-query-RZ010359157.aspx?section=4

Comment: Thanks Paul. Is there any other way apart from this, like in SQL management studio we have?

Comment: can anyone please share idea if there is any?